# Мерч(е/а)ндайзинг - "а" или "е"?

Tags: заимствования

В обиходе активно используются оба варианта - и "мерч***а***ндайзинг", и "мерч***е***ндайзинг".
Как всё-таки нужно писать это заимствованное слово?

Answer (score 2):

Слово происходит от английского "merchandising", где А читается как Э. Поэтому ближе к оригиналу будет "мерчендайзинг". Но это такое же разночтение, как "ланч-ленч", "сандвич-сендвич".

Answer (score 1):

учебник для вуза называется "Организация мерчендайзинга"

Answer (score 0):

В орфографическом словаре — мерчандайзинг.

Answer (score 0):

Почему мы должны ограничиваться одним вариантом? Пусть оба варианта имеют право на существование. В английском вообще соответствующий гласный не произносится (редуцирован в устной речи, как и многие безударные гласные).